# Почему Android Canvas медленнее OpenGL ES?

Tags: java, android, canvas, opengl, opengles

Почему OpenGL дает большую производительность при создании графических приложений?
Как работает Canvas и чем его способ отрисовки графики отличается от OpenGL-го? Т.е. за счет чего меньшая производительность?

Answer (score 4):

Так всегда было, что в виндовс что в андроид. OpenGL общается напрямую с видеодрайвером и использует буфер вывода. Т.е. ты в начале рисуешь картинку по кусочкам, но на экране ничего не изменяется, это все происходит в памяти видеокарты(очень быстро). Потом когда твой кадр готов, ты даешь команду отобразить буфер, и в видеопамяти проходит замена буферов(swap - буфер отображаемый заменяется отрисованным)и ты сразу видишь готовую отрисованную картинку. Canvas же использует системные инструменты и на экран выводится каждый пиксел(а это затраты по времени). В основном прирост производительности это использование буферов.

Comment: использование буферов и плюс множество ядер видеокарты способных делать однотипные операции намного быстрее чем процессор

Comment: "Системные инструменты" - имеется ввиду, центральный процессор? То есть Canvas не использует возможности видеокарты? Или использует, но не на 100%?)

Comment: Canvas никак не общается с видеокартой напрямую, как это делает OpenGL, канвас использует в качестве посредника систему, ну типо говорит вот тут пиксель засвети таким цветом, тут таким, и он не один такой, еще есть форма, кнопки, пункты меню-все хотят перерисоваться.